# Making a YouTube Webpage and taking user feedback using a if else condition

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a feedback button and I have made the code for the same but it is not working. Below, I have attached parts of my code which are JS codes. I am new here and I am also a little new to HTML so in simple language I want the updated code :)

I have added the whole code below - I don't find any problem with the code.
If I run my code the output is almost correct except when I click on the button and write something in the prompt box and click ok, no text appears!

```
<button id= "Feedback"onclick="MyFunction()">Feedback Form</button>
                <p id = "demo"></p>
        <script>
            function MyFunction(){
                var feedback= prompt("Hi! Put all your comments here, we would love to hear you :)", "good")
                var msg;
                
                if(feedback=="good"){
                        msg="I am happy to hear that! Enjoy Watching!";
                        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=msg;
                }
                     else if(feedback=="informative"){
                        msg="That is fantastic, a total video based encyclopedia, Enjoy Watching! ";
                        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=msg;
                }
                else if(feedback=="funny"){
                        msg="Same here! Even I laughed a lot, Enjoy Watching!";
                        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=msg;
                }
                else if(feedback=="motivational"){
                        msg="That is superb, Enjoy Watching!";
                        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=msg;
                }
                else if(feedback=="happy"){
                        msg= "I am so glad you liked it, Enjoy Watching!";
                        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=msg;
                }
                else{
                    msg="We will surely look into it!";
                    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=msg;
                }
            }
        </script>
```

THIS QUESTION HAS BEEN ANSWERED!

Comment: Hi, try to be a little more specific. You say that it's not working, so what's happening? Do you get a error, no output at all?

Comment: Yes sure, No error actually, I do get the output and also the prompt box once I click the button. But even if I agree to the if else conditions like even if I enter "good" or "happy" it doesn't show me anything, no matter what feedback is entered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is good. Maybe in the HTML you are not referencing the JavaScript.

Add `<script src="./the/route/to/my/javascript/file/index.js"></script>` before the end of the `body` tag.

You can see that the code is working here:
https://codepen.io/carlos-dubon/pen/VwaRvEp

**EDIT:**

```
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Feedback Form</button>
    <p id="myPElement">
      <!-- Output will show here -->
    </p>

    <script>
      function myFunction() {
        var feedback = prompt(
          "Hi! Put all your comments here, we would love to hear you :)",
          "good",
          null
        );

        var msg = "";

        var p = document.getElementById("myPElement");

        if (feedback == "good") {
          msg = "I am happy to hear that! Enjoy Watching!";
          p.innerHTML = msg;
        } else if (feedback == "informative") {
          msg =
            "That is fantastic, a total video based encyclopedia, Enjoy Watching! ";
          p.innerHTML = msg;
        } else if (feedback == "funny") {
          msg = "Same here! Even I laughed a lot, Enjoy Watching!";
          p.innerHTML = msg;
        } else if (feedback == "motivational") {
          msg = "That is superb, Enjoy Watching!";
          p.innerHTML = msg;
        } else if (feedback == "happy") {
          msg = "I am so glad you liked it, Enjoy Watching!";
          p.innerHTML = msg;
        } else {
          msg = "We will surely look into it!";
          p.innerHTML = msg;
        }
      }
    </script>
```

Try copy pasting this. It works here.

Comment: I am actually adding the JS codes in the HTML file itself using the <script> tags

Comment: Yes I don't know why it doesn't work on mine. The output is almost correct I also get  the prompt box once I click the button. But even if I agree to the if else conditions like even if I enter "good" or "happy" it doesn't show me anything, no matter what feedback is entered.

Comment: Upload your entire project and give us a link. It's a problem of project structure, not code.

Comment: I have uploaded my entire project, check the question again and please solve the error

Comment: And can you please edit my code only. As I have to show this to someone and I have to do it using the code I gave only ..

Answer (score 1):

Hey I used your code and everything is working fine. I don't see any problem. If it is semantically, meaning the behaviour please elaborate on the problem.

```html
<button id= "Feedback"onclick="MyFunction()">Feedback Form</button>
<p id = "demo"></p>

<script>
            function MyFunction(){
                var feedback= prompt("Hi! Put all your comments here, we would love to hear you :)", "good")
                var msg;
                
                if(feedback=="good"){
                        msg="I am happy to hear that! Enjoy Watching!";
                        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=msg;
                }
                     else if(feedback=="informative"){
                        msg="That is fantastic, a total video based encyclopedia, Enjoy Watching! ";
                        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=msg;
                }
                else if(feedback=="funny"){
                        msg="Same here! Even I laughed a lot, Enjoy Watching!";
                        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=msg;
                }
                else if(feedback=="motivational"){
                        msg="That is superb, Enjoy Watching!";
                        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=msg;
                }
                else if(feedback=="happy"){
                        msg= "I am so glad you liked it, Enjoy Watching!";
                        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=msg;
                }
                else{
                    msg="We will surely look into it!";
                    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=msg;
                }
            }
        </script>
```

Maybe you'll need to load your script after the HTML was loaded. Position the script-tag at the end or use the onload functionality.

Comment: Yes sure, I do get the output and also the prompt box once I click the button. But even if I agree to the if else conditions like even if I enter "good" or "happy" it doesn't show me anything, no matter what feedback is entered. This is the behavior of the program and one more thing I am adding the JS Codes using the <script> tags in the html file itself, there is no separate JS File